# Django uwsgi gets killed

Tags: python, django, nginx, web-deployment, uwsgi

The uwsgi gets killed and we could receive a core dump file generated with following logs. Anyone faced a similar issue. Please guide...
Platform: Ubuntu 16.04

```
Program terminated with signal SIGQUIT, Quit.
#0  __lll_lock_wait () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:135
135 ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7eff0c4d5700 (LWP 6239))]
(gdb) 
(gdb) bt
#0  __lll_lock_wait () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:135
#1  0x00007eff0c0badbd in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x70b028 <uwsgi+6248>) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:80
#2  0x000000000041f265 in wsgi_req_accept ()
#3  0x0000000000467856 in simple_loop_run ()
#4  0x000000000046765e in simple_loop ()
#5  0x000000000046befa in uwsgi_ignition ()
#6  0x000000000047063d in uwsgi_worker_run ()
#7  0x0000000000470c20 in uwsgi_run ()
#8  0x000000000041e76e in main ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: Something is trying to release a lock on a mutex that it is currently owned by something else.

From the information in your core dump it seems to be a bug in your version of uwsgi. Try an update.

Comment: uWSGI==2.0.17.1, version used

Comment: Sorry, I don't work with uWSGI, I do a little systems programming in Linux so I'm familiar with the cause of the error. There's always the possibility of your glibc having a bug but it's so remote that I think you should consider changing uWSGI versions first